# How to reference Silverlight control library's style sheet at design time?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a SL4 controls project and I am trying to reference a style sheet within that project from a control which is also inside of the project. The problem is that the the styles do not get applied at design time and I can't see what the controls look like... :(

Is there a way to remedy this?

Thanks,

Martin

Edit:

The project is called SilverlightControls. Inside of it I have a folder called Resources.
In the folder there is a resource dictionary file called ControlStyles: `<ResourceDictionary x:Name="CustomControlStyles"></ResourceDictionary>` which defines a few styles.

Within the controls I reference the styles as follows:

`<ProfileForm ... Style="{StaticResource ProfileFormStyle}"/>`

Comment: Show us how are you referencing your styles.

Comment: @NestorArturo I just added how I reference the styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add your resource dictionary as a merged dictionary in each xaml control file.  Like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/SilverlightControls;component/Resources/CustomControlStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Another way to do this would be using a theme and Custom Controls, but this would mean your custom controls are lookless, and from your question, it doesn't seem like they are.  If you want to learn more about themes and custom controls, you can check it out [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-a-Silverlight-Custom-Control-The-Basics.aspx)